# Refresh jQuery plugin after css media query request

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone knows if there is a way to refresh/reload jquery under css media queries changes?

I have created an example with this situation: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23044665/index.html

If you resize the browser less than 960 pixels the browser apply the media query BUT the jQuery plugin area width stays at 960 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the plugin is adding the widths of the slides and the container as attributes of the the HTML, e.g. `style="width:960"` which will override anything in your style sheets/media query.

I would recommend that you use a different slider plugin tbh - [this one](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) is built for rersponsiveness and automatically recalculates everything when you resize the browser

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! I´ll try it soon!!! Thanks a lot to let me know about this plugin!! I think it will save me loads of time!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        slider.reloadShow();
    });
```

Comment: +1 for adding the code :) and as per my answer, good to suggest doing this on orientationchange too for tablet/mobile

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform additional JavaScript operations when the screen size changes then add listeners for orientationchange and resize to catch the browser changing size or a tilt on tablet/phone.